# Why does "ls > foo" produce a file containing "foo"?

Tags: command-line

I removed all files in a directory and then ran `ls > foo` in that same directory.

Running `cat foo` reveals that the newly created file "foo" contains "foo". Why is the file "foo" not empty? When `ls` executes, there are no files in the directory yet, right?

Comment: interesting question!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `>` command line directive happens before the `ls` command is executed.  The shell has to be ready to save the output that the `ls` command may produce, so it has to create and open the file for writing.

When `ls` is executed by the shell, the `foo` file exists and hence `ls` outputs "foo" which is what you found in the file `foo`.

Comment: Ah, so in general, when using `someCommand > fileName`, the OS will create the new file first before executing `someCommand`. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't like that, you can do something like `ls | (sleep 2; cat > foo)`, where 2 is 2 seconds to wait before opening that file with `cat`.